# How to use a Loop in Angular to display a link multiple times

Tags: angular

I have a link in Angular that displays a number of user selectable avatars. I have around 100 of these avatars and don't want to hard code the link into my code. I just want to be able to tell angular how many there are and to display this link this many times.

Each link has a click event attached to it that selects the avatar and this corresponds to the file name as seen below.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="avatarSelectVisitor(1)"><img src="assets/avatars/1.png" class="partnerAvatar" ></a>
```

What's the best way for me to replicate this line without having to copy and paste it 100 times?

Comment: Use `*ngFor` : https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: NgFor requires an array - I don't have an array I have a range of numbers

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Is there a reason you can't just convert that range of numbers into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating a directive `src/app/directives/ng-times.directives.ts`:

```js
import {Directive, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * A simple directive which iterates a HTML template for given "X" times.
 *
 * @author Shashank Agrawal
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[appNgTimes]'
})
export class NgTimesDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() appNgTimes;

    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        Array.from(Array(this.appNgTimes)).forEach((item, index) => {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {index});
        });
    }
}
```

And then use it in HTML:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="avatarSelectVisitor(i + 1)" *appNgTimes="100; let i = index">
    <img src="assets/avatars/{{i + 1}}.png" class="partnerAvatar">
</a>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
<div>
  <a *ngFor="let num of numbers" class="dropdown-item" >
    <img [src]="'assets/avatars/' + num + '.png'" [alt]="'assets/avatars/' + num + '.png'" alt="" class="partnerAvatar">
  </a>
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  numbers = Array.from(Array(100).keys());
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a1q7y2?file=src/app/app.component.html